# sample data not show in new theme

Tags: magento2

i`m trying to make a new theme and i setup the new theme structure like this :

```
TestVender/
└── TestTheme
    ├── etc
    ├── media
    │   └── TestPreview.jpg
    ├── registration.php
    ├── theme.xml
    └── web
        ├── css
        ├── images
        └── js
```

after all this i found my theme in the configuration > design .
But i can not see any the sample data that i found in luma theme can any one tell me why ?

Answer (score 3):

its very simple, home blocks are not assigned to the home page while we create new theme. We only do it manually.

please follow the instruction

login to admin, then navigate to

**Content->Pages**

find **Home Page** then in action column click **edit** then

click the **Content** tab then place the below value in text area

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="home-page-block"}}
```

note: here block id mention unique id of blocks, you could found the list blocks and block id under **Content->Blocks**

finally **save page**

then clear your cache of magento and browser, load the home page, you could see the home page look like luma home page.

if you want to find home page html content, find block **home-page-block** under the **Content->Blocks** then edit the block you could see the html content of home page.

have Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

First, Magento does not recommend inheriting from the Luma theme. Magento only recommend inheriting from the blank theme.

You are not able to see `sample data` because `sample data` is currently linked to a specific theme `Magento/luma.`

For example, Go into the `Admin > Content` section, then look at a `Footer Links` widget added by `sample data`.
[image]

For more detail, please check this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1929

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that my product sample data was not displaying when switching to my new theme but was visible in the admin products section. This is because the category settings have been reset. To rectify this complete the following steps:

1. Login to admin
2. Products > Categories > Select Category e.g. "Womens"
3. Display Settings > Display Mode > Set to "Products/Static block and Products"
4. Anchor > Set to "Yes"
5. Repeat for each cateogry

[image]